# How do I make an array from inputted information (i.e. names) and then use it as objects within the code?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been reading up on it, but every question I've found has asked for slightly different things, such as only wanting a single letter for their array, or in a different language (I'm new and only learning java at the moment), so here I am.

I want to set up an array that uses the user's input for their names.

What I have so far is this, I'm assuming this is the declaration line, where later I use an input line to define a value within the array (which I also am unsure how to do)

```
String[] array = {"name"};
```

But I don't know how to for example print.out the object or keep up with which name will be what value. I appreciate your time taken to teach me!

EDIT for further clarification. I'm trying to write up a small app that asks the user for numerous names, addresses, and phone numbers (Type name -> Type name's address -> type name's phone number, ask if they want to add another person, if yes then go back to asking for another name)

I am unsure how to set up a String array or how to use it throughout. However, thanks to your input and coming back after some fresh air, I have a better idea how to word it for google. Thank you guys for your help, even if it was just to gesture a better articulated question.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do exactly. Do you want a String array which stores users input and then use the array in code? Am i right?

Comment: I also don't understand what you want to do. Explain what your program should do, at a higher level. And show what you tried.

Comment: `System.out.println(array[0]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is a sequence of values. You have created an array of Strings that is one String long. To access the value at a specific of an array, use **array subscript notation:** the name of the array followed by a pair of square brackets (`[]`) with the index in between them.

```
String[] anArrayOfStrings = {"string0", "string1", "string2"};

anArrayOfStrings[0]; //the first element

System.out.println(anArrayOfStrings[1]); //print the second element

anArrayOfStrings[2] = "new string value"; //assign the third element to a new value

if (anArrayOfStrings[0].equals("string0") //evaluate the first element and call a method
{
     //this block will execute anArrayOfStrings[0] is "string0"
} 

anArrayOfStrings[3]; //error, index out of bounds
```

Simply declaring the array would be

```
String[] names;
```

In your code you both declare and assign it in the same line by using an initializer list. 
To assign individual elements, use the `[]` notation. Note that once you initialized you list to be only one String long, it cannot become longer than without be re-assigned. To declare an array of any size, you can use:

```
 String[] arrayWithInitialSize = new String[5]; //holds five strings, each null to begin with
```

Comment: so given your snippets, and wanting 3 separate string arrays, I would need to declare the three arrays as so:

    String[] Name;
    String[] Address;
    String[] Phonenum;

correct? I also want the arrays to be undefined until the user, through a scanner line, defines them. Would that go as so?

    system.out.println("name?");
    Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);

Comment: @formn If you want three associated Strings, you can just make an array that is three Strings long. If you want three arrays of some length of Strings, you can declare them separately.

Comment: For the array that is three Strings long, that means I can use your first line of code and change the stringX to name/address/numbers?

Comment: Thank you very much! I greatly appreciate your patience with me. I have a book for reference, but learning from another person just seems to click in my head much more quickly. Thank you again.